# Is there a way to use regexpvalidator with input mask in qml textfield?

Tags: qt, qml

I need to use input mask like that `"#99\u00B099.9999\u2032"` for latitude input.

At the same time I need to validate symbols with regex like that `/^[\-\+]?((0|([1-8]\d?))(\.[0-5]{1}\d{1}\.\d{4})?|90(\.0{2}\.0{4})?)$/`.

How do I use both at the same time?

Comment: Your regex and input mask must be coherent, It seems like they don't.

Comment: @ניר yeah, but if I change regex to smth like that: /^[\-\+]?((0|([1-8]\d?))(\u00b0[0-5]{1}\d{1}\.\d{4})?|90(\.0{2}\.0{1,4}\u2032)?)$/ it still doesn't works

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/) website, might help you with validating that regex.